# USB mount not able to auto mount external drive due to MTP error

Tags: usb, raspbian-stretch, hard-drive, mount, systemd

I'm trying to auto mount external hard drives to raspberry pi B+ (raspbian stretch lite image) using usbmount ([link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=205016#p1271455)). But auto mount fails with the below error saying the device is not MTP. Unlike this [suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/1206664/disable-mtp-udev-rules-for-specific-device-so-it-can-be-mount-as-a-usb-mass-stor) I am looking for a way to enable usbmount to mount any usb hdd without specifying device id. How can I do this?

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-udevd
● systemd-udevd.service - udev Kernel Device Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-08-24 14:50:00 UTC; 52min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-udevd.service(8)
           man:udev(7)
 Main PID: 131 (systemd-udevd)
   Status: "Processing with 16 children at max"
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-udevd.service
           └─131 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd

Aug 24 14:50:00 3c-rpi mtp-probe[158]: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Aug 24 14:50:01 3c-rpi mtp-probe[207]: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Aug 24 14:50:01 3c-rpi mtp-probe[208]: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.1"
Aug 24 14:50:01 3c-rpi mtp-probe[208]: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Aug 24 14:50:02 3c-rpi systemd-udevd[284]: Process '/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add' failed with exit code 1.
Aug 24 15:28:33 3c-rpi mtp-probe[1104]: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2"
Aug 24 15:28:33 3c-rpi mtp-probe[1104]: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device
Aug 24 15:28:34 3c-rpi systemd-udevd[1106]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
Aug 24 15:28:34 3c-rpi systemd-udevd[1112]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
Aug 24 15:28:34 3c-rpi systemd-udevd[1105]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: please edit your post so that you are asking a question .... right now you are only describing what you are doing ...... also, you may find an answer on a linux website, since the failure is not RPi related

Comment: `without specifying device id` .... what happens if you do not specify the ID?